# What is the best .NET type for collections where each key can have multiple values?

Tags: c#

I have one key but different values for that key. I tried HashTable but I don't think that is the right way of doing it.

I'll explain in detail what the requirement is:

I have a Key - "Asp.net" - for that I have n number of values - 61, 67, 100

So I have to store this somewhere like Dictionary or hash table.

Comment: I made your title match what you're looking for so that people reading on the front page know what you want.

Comment: Me too... right after you, @BillyONeal, apparently.  If yours was better than mine, please feel free to update it again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` would do the trick for your sample data.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
dictionary.Add("asp.net", new List<int>());
dictionary["asp.net"].Add(61);
dictionary["asp.net"].Add(67);
dictionary["asp.net"].Add(100);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want PowerCollections MultiDictionary.

http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections

Comment: Just FYI: that is one of the two "correct" (as in: most widely used) names for that datastructure, just in case you ever need to search for one for another language/platform. The other would be `MultiMap`.

Answer (score 2):

If both your key and values are string you may want to use [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx).

NameValueCollection class stores multiple string values under a single key. Acording to MSDN, this class can be used for headers, query strings and form data.