# Is there a single key and multi value data structure in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I would like to store multiple values for a single key and must be able to retrieve the specific value.

Is there any data structure in Java which have this kind of functionality? If so, please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use `Map<key,List<T>>`

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> map;
```

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554455/hashtable-with-mutiple-values-for-single-key the hash table with list solution. Which one is the best..?

Comment: Of course `HashMap`. Have a look at [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable)

Comment: it converts itself into a binary tree after a specific threshold which takes search time as log(n)

Answer (score 8):

There is no support in JDK. What you want is a `Multimap` and [guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides it.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with `Map<Key, List<Element>>`?